# opencv much slower in multithreading

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv

Im writting a console application that uses multithreading. Each thread process a set of images using opencv functions.

If the function that uses opencv functions is executed in a single thread I get a reference computational time. If I execute this function from multiple threads the function (individually in each thread) is much slower (nearly double), when it should be nearly the same.

¿Does opencv parallelizes, serializes or blocks itself the execution?.

I have test the aplication using opencv libraries compiled WITH_TBB and without TBB and the result is almost the same. I don't know if it may have any inffluence, but I have seen also that some functions like cv::threshold or cv::findcontours create 12 additional subprocesses when beein executed. If The open cv calls are commented the time is the same for all threads and is the same to the obtained in a single thread execution, so in this case the multithreading is working well. The question is if there is maybe an opencv compilation option or a function call that allows to obtain the same time in multithreading and in single threading execution??.

EDIT
This is the result of increasing the number of threads (cores) in a 4 cores CPU, executing with 1, 2, 3 and 4 cores the same function. Each core process 768 images with 1600x1200 resolution in a for loop. Inside the loop the function causing the increasing delay is called. I shoud expect that, independently of the number of cores the time is approx the same obtained for a single thread (35000ms) or 10% more, but, as can be seen the time raises up when the number of threads is increased, I can not find why...

TIMES: (Sorry, the system not allow me to upload images to the posts)

```
time in File No. 3 --> 35463
 Mean time using 1 cores is: 47ms

time in File No. 3 --> 42747
 time in File No. 3 --> 42709
 Mean time using 2 cores is: 28ms

time in File No. 3 --> 54587
 time in File No. 3 --> 54595
 time in File No. 3 --> 54437
 Mean time using 3 cores is: 24ms

time in File No. 3 --> 68751
 time in File No. 3 --> 68865
 time in File No. 3 --> 68878
 time in File No. 3 --> 68622
 Mean time using 4 cores is: 22ms
```

If no opencv code is used insithe the function, the time, as expected, is similar for all the cases 1, 2 3 or 4 threads but when an open cv function is used, for example only with a a simple call to:

img.convertTo(img,CV_32F);

beeing img a cv::Mat, the time increases when the number of threads is increased. I have made test also disabling the hiper-threading option in the CPU Bios. In that case all the times decrease, been the time with 1 thread 25.000ms, but the problem of time increase is still present (33sec with 2 threads, 43 with 3, 57 with 4)... I dont know if this tells you something

## Edit 2

A mcve:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <future>
#include <chrono>
#include "Filter.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <future>


#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

long long Ticks();
int WithOpencv(cv::Mat img);
int With_OUT_Opencv(cv::Mat img);
int TestThreads (char *buffer,std::string file);
#define Blur3x3(matrix,f,c) ((matrix[(f-1)*1600+(c-1)] + matrix[(f-1)*1600+c] + matrix[(f-1)*1600+(c+1)] + matrix[f*1600+(c-1)] + matrix[f*1600+c] + matrix[f*1600+(c+1)] + matrix[(f+1)*1600+(c-1)] + matrix[(f+1)*1600+c] + matrix[(f+1)*1600+(c+1)])/9)


int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{

    std::string file="Test.bmp";

    auto function = [&](char *buffer){return TestThreads(buffer,file);};
    char *buffers[12];
    std::future<int> frames[12];
    DWORD tid;
    int i,j;
    int nframes = 0;
    int ncores;

    cv::setNumThreads(8);

    for (i=0;i<8;i++) buffers[i] = new char[1000*1024*1024];
    for (j=1;j<9;j++)
    {
        ncores = j;
        long long t = Ticks();
        for (i=0;i<ncores;i++) frames[i] = std::async(std::launch::async,function,buffers[i]);
        for (i=0;i<ncores;i++) nframes += frames[i].get();
        t = Ticks() - t;

        std::cout << "Mean time using " << ncores << " cores is: " << t/nframes << "ms" << std::endl << std::endl;
        nframes = 0;
        Sleep(2000);
    }
    for (int i=0;i<8;i++) delete buffers[i];

    return NULL;

    return 0;
}



int TestThreads (char *buffer,std::string file)
{

    long long ta;
    int res;

        char *ruta=new char[file.length() + 1];
        strcpy(ruta,file.c_str());


        cv::Mat img (1200, 1600, CV_8UC1);
        img=cv::imread(file);


        ta = Ticks();
        for (int i=0;i<15;i++) {

            //Uncomment this and comment next line to test without opencv calls. With_OUT_Opencv implements simple filters with direct operations over mat data
            //res = With_OUT_Opencv(img);

            res = WithOpencv(img);


        }

        ta = Ticks() - ta;
        std::cout << "Time in file No. 3--> " << ta << std::endl;


        return 15;
}



int WithOpencv(cv::Mat img){

    cv::Mat img_bin;    
    cv::Mat img_filtered;
    cv::Mat img_filtered2;
    cv::Mat img_res;
    int Crad_morf=2;
    double Tthreshold=20;
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2*Crad_morf + 1, 2*Crad_morf+1));

    img.convertTo(img,CV_32F);
    cv::blur(img, img_filtered, cv::Size(3, 3));
    cv::blur(img.mul(img), img_filtered2, cv::Size(3, 3));
    cv::sqrt(img_filtered2 - img_filtered.mul(img_filtered), img_res);
    cv::normalize(img_res, img_res, 0.0, 1.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    img_res.convertTo(img_res,CV_8UC1,255.0);
    cv::threshold(img_res, img_bin, Tthreshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);

    if (Crad_morf!=0){
        cv::dilate(img_bin, img_bin, element);
    }

    return 0;
}





int With_OUT_Opencv(cv::Mat img){

    unsigned char *baux1 = new unsigned char[1600*1200];
    unsigned short *baux2 = new unsigned short[1600*1200];
    unsigned char max=0; 
    int f,c,i;
    unsigned char threshold = 177;

    for (f=1;f<1199;f++)                                // Bad Blur filters
    {
        for (c=1; c<1599; c++)
        {
            baux1[f*1600+c] = Blur3x3(img.data,f,c);
            baux1[f*1600+c] = baux1[f*1600+c] * baux1[f*1600+c];
            baux2[f*1600+c] = img.data[f*1600+c] * img.data[f*1600+c];
        }
    }
    for (f=1;f<1199;f++)
    {
        for (c=1; c<1599; c++)
        {
            baux1[f*1600+c] = sqrt(Blur3x3(baux2,f,c) - baux1[f*1600+c]);
            if (baux1[f*1600+c] > max) max = baux1[f*1600+c];
        }
    }
    threshold = threshold * ((float)max/255.0);         // Bad Norm/Bin
    for (i=0;i<1600*1200;i++)
    {
        if (baux1[i]>threshold) baux1[i] = 1;
        else baux1[i] = 0;
    }

    delete []baux1;
    delete []baux2;

    return 0;
}




long long Ticks()
{
   static long long last = 0;
   static unsigned ticksPerMS = 0;
   LARGE_INTEGER largo;

   if (last==0)
   {
       QueryPerformanceFrequency(&largo);
       ticksPerMS = (unsigned)(largo.QuadPart/1000);
       QueryPerformanceCounter(&largo);
       last = largo.QuadPart;
       return 0;
   }
   QueryPerformanceCounter(&largo);
   return (largo.QuadPart-last)/ticksPerMS;
}
```

Comment: 1) what does your function do? 2) don't forget that disk IO can be a bottleneck too 3) try setting the value of `setNumThreads(...)` to 1 or 0: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/core/doc/utility_and_system_functions_and_macros.html#void setNumThreads(int nthreads)

Comment: 1) Basically it does two blurs, some muliply operations, one threshold, dilate and find contours. 2) No IO operations are made in the function, all reading operations are made before. Finally, when setting the number of threads with cv::setNumThreads() to 0 or 1, the subprocesses created in the threshold or findcontours call are gone, but the time increase when I increase the threads (in the application, not opencv ones) is the same... Thank you for your response!!

Comment: How much time increase per iteration (=function call) and how many iterations are done per second? Creating a thread (native c++11 thread or any other OS native thread) costs time, and the scheduler needs to switch to it. The cost should be anything between a few microseconds to a couple of milliseconds (depends on how many threads are being executed at the same time). As a rule of thumb, if no blocking (file IO/network), create just as many threads as the total number of cores on your CPU(s). To help you further, you'd need to share some code as part of an stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: For example, if your CPU has 4 cores and you run 40 threads, there will be 10 scheduled context switches per core. If all those 40 threads are only doing brute CPU processing, running 40 threads will be slower than running 4 threads.

Comment: Your timing code is likely wrong; you should include that, as well.

Comment: time in File No. means total time processing the 768 images (one function call) 35 seconds, 42 seconds,... Mean time means the whole mean time per image treated by all threads.

Comment: I have made a test project that reproduces the behaviour. You can download the full code (zip file) in [link](https://goo.gl/3nOaZX). Buffers when creating threads are not used, but are keeped to simulate the application. This is for a 4 cores CPU (8 with HT enabled) and 12 Gb RAM with opencv+tbb installed. In the function _italic_TestThreads you will see two funtions inside the for loop, one with opencv calls and the othre with no calls to open cv. Comment one or other to see the difference in times. Thanks a lot!!

Comment: @tofi9, could you run the project??

Answer (score 1):

I'm confused as to what your question is.

Your initial question suggested that running x number of iterations in serial is considerably faster than running **them** in parallel. *Note*: when the same target function is used. And you're wondering why running the same target function is considerably slower in a multithreaded scenario.

However, I now see that your example is comparing the performance of OpenCV with some other custom code. Is that what your question is about?

Related to the question as I initially thought the question was, the answer is: no, running the target function in serial is not considerably faster than running it in parallel. See results and code below.

#### Results

```
eight threads took 4104.38 ms
single thread took 7272.68 ms
four threads took 3687 ms
two threads took 4500.15 ms
```

(on a Apple MBA 2012 i5 & opencv3)

#### Test code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <thread>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>

using namespace std;
using namespace std::chrono;
using namespace cv;

class benchmark {
    time_point<steady_clock> start = steady_clock::now();
    string title;
public:
    benchmark(const string& title) : title(title) {}
    
    ~benchmark() {
        auto diff = steady_clock::now() - start;
        cout << title << " took " << duration <double, milli> (diff).count() << " ms" << endl;
    }
};

template <typename F>
void repeat(unsigned n, F f) {
    while (n--) f();
};



int targetFunction(Mat img){
    cv::Mat img_bin;
    cv::Mat img_filtered;
    cv::Mat img_filtered2;
    cv::Mat img_res;
    int Crad_morf=2;
    double Tthreshold=20;
    cv::Mat element = cv::getStructuringElement(cv::MORPH_ELLIPSE, cv::Size(2*Crad_morf + 1, 2*Crad_morf+1));
    
    img.convertTo(img,CV_32F);
    cv::blur(img, img_filtered, cv::Size(3, 3));
    cv::blur(img.mul(img), img_filtered2, cv::Size(3, 3));
    cv::sqrt(img_filtered2 - img_filtered.mul(img_filtered), img_res);
    cv::normalize(img_res, img_res, 0.0, 1.0, cv::NORM_MINMAX);
    img_res.convertTo(img_res,CV_8UC1,255.0);
    cv::threshold(img_res, img_bin, Tthreshold, 255, cv::THRESH_BINARY);
    
    if (Crad_morf!=0){
        cv::dilate(img_bin, img_bin, element);
    }
    
    //imshow("WithOpencv", img_bin);
    
    return 0;
}

void runTargetFunction(int nIterations, int nThreads, const Mat& img) {
    int nIterationsPerThread = nIterations / nThreads;
    vector<thread> threads;
    auto targetFunctionFn = [&img]() {
        targetFunction(img);
    };
    
    setNumThreads(nThreads);
    
    repeat(nThreads, [&] {
        threads.push_back(thread([=]() {
            repeat(nIterationsPerThread, targetFunctionFn);
        }));
    });
    
    for(auto& thread : threads)
        thread.join();
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string file = "../../opencv-test/Test.bmp";
    auto img = imread(file);
    
    const int nIterations = 64;
    
    // let's run using eight threads
    {
        benchmark b("eight threads");
        runTargetFunction(nIterations, 8, img);
    }
    
    // let's run using a single thread
    {
        benchmark b("single thread");
        runTargetFunction(nIterations, 1, img);
    }
    
    // let's run using four threads
    {
        benchmark b("four threads");
        runTargetFunction(nIterations, 4, img);
    }
    
    // let's run using a two threads
    {
        benchmark b("two threads");
        runTargetFunction(nIterations, 2, img);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The intention with the other custom code was to show that when you call the other function instead of WithOpencv, the behaviour is as expected to be, the time is more or less equal no matter the number of threads used, so you have anser the question.

Comment: In your code, the iterations made by each thread depends on the number of threads because are distributed in int nIterationsPerThread=nIterations / nThreads; , but EACH thread should execute the same number of iterations. Please try with a fixed number of iterations per thread, this is the behaviuor im asking for. The more the threads, the more time for fixed number of iterations, when more or less the same time (with approx 10-20% of increment when more threads are added) as in a SINGLE thread execution should be expected independently of the number of threads. Or im I wrong assuming it??.

Comment: if you use as targetfunction the function With_OUT_Opencv, you should see that this is happening (time is more or less the same with some increase for more threads), but when you use the opencv instructions, the code is not palallelizing, and the total time raises linearly when adding more threads.

Comment: I'm not sure I do understand your comments, but it seems like you're missing some basic knowledge regarding threads. The example above shows that if *the required work is to iterate 64 times*, then I can decide to iterate 64 times in serial (takes 7s), or in parallel - two at a time (takes 4s), or parallel - four at a time... etc... if your question is, why is iterating 128 times in parallel slower than iterating 64 times in serial, then the answer is clear: 128 times is more than 64 times; two cores != 2x the speed of a single core.

Comment: Regarding your question, why is the total running time x seconds, regardless of how often I iterate through my `non-opencv-custom-function()`: this is not an `opencv` question, I'd suggest creating a separate question for that. I will not reply any further on this, but skimming through your code, it might as well be that the compiler replaces all your implementation with a `NOP` because it found out that running your implementation has no effect on the system.

Comment: Thank you for showing me what is a mcve, is such a hard thing. By the way, revise your code because is not c++. you nicely initialize class members...

Comment: And the next time use the given code, not a beginners version to make others to waste time...

Comment: Pleasure to help. Not sure why you're saying that my code is 'not c++'. it compiles with no warnings and runs fine on my machine (XCode 6.1 & CLang/LLVM 3.6).

Answer (score 1):

You are measuring three things:

- The time that all threads need to complete the whole task divided by the size of the whole task.
- The time required by each individual thread to complete its part of the task.
- The time required to complete the whole task.

You are observing that the first time is going down from 47ms to 22ms when increasing the number of threads. That is good! At the same time you are realizing that the time requried by an individual thread increases from  35463 to about 68751 (whatever units). Finally, you are realizing that the overall executing time goes up.

Regarding the second measurement: When increasing the number of threads, the individual threads need longer to perform there respective operations. Two possible explanations:

- Your threads are competing for memory bus bandwidth.
- Your threads are triggering computations that are multi-threaded by themselves, so effectively they are competing with each other for CPU time.

Now for the question why the overall working time increases. The reason is simple: You are not only increasing the number of threads, but you are increasing the work load at the same rate. If your threads were not competing with each other at all and there would be no overhead involved, `N` threads would require the same time to do `N` times the work. It does not, so you are noticing a slow down.

Comment: Thaks Marcur for clarifiying the question. Regarding the two possible explanations, the second one may be a reason in opencv because some of the functions (like cv::threshold) are implemented with parallel_for and they create threads by themselves. If you set cv::setnumThreads(0) they not create their own threads (it is possible to tracks viewing the subprocesses of the task) but in this case the time (second one) also increases. So the first reason could be the right one. Because this only happends when executing the function with opencv calls, I think that this is an opencv issue.

Comment: If I use the other function I can see that the second time increases what theoretically sould increase (much less), but with opencv this increment  in time for each thread is linear, so the parallelization is not working. I feel that opencv should manage this,thats why Im asking for a possible solution regarding the results obtained with the own programmed dummy filters. Regarding your final line I would expect that N threads (doing N times the work, one by thread) would require the same time plus a small linear quantity that 1 thread doing 1 times the work. Like happends in the other function

Comment: @JoséLuisGiral: Regarding your expectations, you'll be disappointed in most real-world situations, at least when using approaches that are *this* simple. They would only be true if there was no sequential code at all and if the threads would not interact or compete with each other at all. Regarding your observations, you may have to accept the fact that OpenCV is so much more efficient than your code that memory bus bandwidth becomes a major concern.